# Rectangle2D .outcode equivalent in C#?

Tags: java, c#, geometry

As the title says: what is Java's .outcode in C#?

Java:

```
public static final Rectangle2D.Double gameField 
    = new Rectangle2D.Double(18, 18, 764, 564);

gameField.outcode(something)
```

C#:

```
public RectangleF gameField= new RectangleF(18, 18, 764, 564);
gameField.???
```

Comment: what is outcode in jave? what does it do ?

Comment: @Boo Determines where the specified coordinates lie with respect to this Rectangle2D. This method computes a binary OR of the appropriate mask values indicating, for each side of this Rectangle2D, whether or not the specified coordinates are on the same side of the edge as the rest of this Rectangle2D.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#outcode(double,%20double)

Comment: This link contains all the methods for C#'s rectangle, but I don't know which one to use:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You may get a better answer than a simple implementation conversion

Comment: There is no equivalent method, at least not on the `RectangleF` class itself, but rolling your own wouldn't be difficult given that the `Right`, `Left`, `Top`, and `Bottom` properties are exposed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm

Comment: @LibertyLocked I'm working with/in Robocode, the code segment is used to describe the Battlefield:
I need .outcode with a algorithm for my robot to aim correctly at other bots

`(int)Math.Sign(gameField.outcode(project(myLocation, absBearing + 0.57 * Math.Sign(latVel), eDistance))`

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Oh my, that's not fun

Comment: You only need the short `ComputeOutcode` routine and a flags enum defining the above/below/left/right/contains constants - Cohen-Sutherlend uses this to do more work.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot So it seems. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Jacklyn I just realized `RectangleF.Contains` returns false when the point is on the bottom right. Updated the code to not use Contains()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .NET `RectangleF` doesn't have this outcode(), I wrote one that is essentially the same.

```
public enum RectOut
{
    Left = 1,
    Top = 2,
    Right = 4,
    Bottom = 8,
}
```

and

```
public static class RectangleFExtensions
{
    public static int Outcode(this RectangleF rect, PointF point)
    {
        int outcode = 0;

        if (rect.Width <= 0) outcode |= (int)RectOut.Left | (int)RectOut.Right;
        if (rect.Height <= 0) outcode |= (int)RectOut.Top | (int)RectOut.Bottom;
        if (point.Y < rect.Top) outcode |= (int)RectOut.Top;
        if (point.Y > rect.Bottom) outcode |= (int)RectOut.Bottom;
        if (point.X < rect.Left) outcode |= (int)RectOut.Left;
        if (point.X > rect.Right) outcode |= (int)RectOut.Right;

        return outcode;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(18f, 18f, 764f, 564f);
int outcode = rect.Outcode(new PointF(18f, 18f));
```

Here is a [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/otKybv)

**Edit:** Apparently `RectangleF.Contains` returns false when the point is on the bottom right. Updated the code to not use Contains()

Comment: @Jacklyn I've made a mistake, and updated the answer and the demo. This is closer to the Java implementation of `outcode`